# can an address autofill change the value of my input?

Tags: html, google-chrome, autocomplete, autofill, street-address

I have an html5 input field with autofill enabled for my address.

```
 <input autocomplete = 'shipping street-address'>
```

When I type, my address shows in a drop-down below my input, however when i select my address from the drop down, nothing happens (i would expect my address to be populated into the input.value)

Do I have to do something in addition to allow address selection to change the input.value to the address i selected?

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: google chrome Version 58.0.3029.81 (64-bit) from a mac that is 10.12.4 (16E195)